# Removing a div class with Javascript or jQuery on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Unsure if anybody is familiar with TypeForm. I am currently testing their forms but its very limited to options with regards to optional items such as incremental question numbers, bullet points & * for required questions.. Ive attached a screenshot of the exact item shown in the dev window that I wish to remove, how is this possible on page load using Javascript or jQuery? i.e. document.getElementsByClassName("Item");

***EDIT***
The way typeform is embedded is as shown in the snippet below:

Much appreciated !! 
[image: item to remove in google chrome dev view]

```html
<div class="typeform-widget" data-url="https://12837r8yhe.typeform.com/to/sKcd9C" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" > </div> <script> (function() { var qs,js,q,s,d=document, gi=d.getElementById, ce=d.createElement, gt=d.getElementsByTagName, id="typef_orm", b="https://embed.typeform.com/"; if(!gi.call(d,id)) { js=ce.call(d,"script"); js.id=id; js.src=b+"embed.js"; q=gt.call(d,"script")[0]; q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q) } })() </script>
```

Comment: Load the jquery file as well, and remove the div see below example.

Comment: It's an iframe, might not work the same for you.

Comment: so not possible to edit from loading on my end? i.e. overwrite

Comment: I am trying to set up an example but its not easy to overwrite values for an iframe, because it is sandboxed.

Answer (score 1):

On page load you can do this to remove all instances of the class

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.Item').remove('Item');
});
```

Or just the class on divs

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div .Item').remove('Item');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the above clear, ive tried and not working, I tried by having a seperate <script></script> beneath the embed code which ive just added to my post. Would this be required to be within the embed code inorder to get the "Item" to not show?

Comment: Do you want the DIV removed or the CLASS on the DIV removed?

Comment: Also, show us what you mean because in order to run what I said yes that code I have has to be in script tags or an external js file

Comment: Yeah just the div.class removed alltogether (or even hidden/invisible), i just find it abit misleading for how i wish to use these forms. So beneath the embed code i had another  <script>$(document).ready(function(){...
})</script> and all the other tries ppl have suggested but no luck

Comment: I changed my answer then you want to use remove but that will entirely remove it. You can also change .remove to .hide if you only want to hide them. Give us your actual HTML and we can help more

Comment: Ive added a snippet you can run to see the form, hopefully thats of help

Answer (score 0):

$("div.item").remove() should do the trick as long as there arent other divs with the item class..

```html
$('div.item').remove();
```

or

```html
$('div.item').first().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove or hide it using jquery when the page loads. But it will remove all the `div` items which have class `.item`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div.item").remove();
  console.log("removed");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Div item was here but removed when page loaded.</p>
<div class="item">1 ></div><span>Just before me</span>
```